# Optimizing a vba macro to work on multiple rows with one parameter

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to optimize an excel macro that I'm running for multiple rows but not sure if is possible to do so.

Basically, I have a file where I run multiple times the formula `=Rand()` in some cells in order to identify the best alpha for a calculation.

I'm running it for different SKUs in different rows, so in VBA I did basically it:

```
Sub Optimization()

'Parameters
MaxX = 0
MaxY = 0
Target = 0.003

'How many calculations should Optimization run
For x = 1 To 1000
Cells(2, 2) = x 'Populate the amount of calculations revised on the specific cell

'SKU X analysis
If Cells(4, 188) > MaxX And Cells(4, 189) <= Target Then alphaX1 = Cells(4, 66)
If Cells(4, 188) > MaxX And Cells(4, 189) <= Target Then alphaX2 = Cells(4, 67)

'SKU Y analysis
If Cells(5, 188) > MaxY And Cells(5, 189) <= Target Then alphaY1 = Cells(5, 66)
If Cells(5, 188) > MaxY And Cells(5, 189) <= Target Then alphaY2 = Cells(5, 67)

If Cells(4, 188) > MaxX Then MaxY = Cells(4, 188)
If Cells(5, 188) > MaxY Then MaxX = Cells(5, 188)

'New cells to fulfill alpha
'X alpha
Cells(4, 68) = alphaX1
Cells(4, 69) = alphaX2

'Y alpha
Cells(5, 68) = alphaY1
Cells(5, 69) = alphaY2

Next x

End Sub
```

Basically, I want to maximize the result of Cells(R, 188) changing the values of `=Rand()`, found at Cells(R, 66) and Cells(R, 67).

I have it done for more than 200 SKUs (in the example I'm including only two SKUs), but macro takes to long to run (for this reason I'm seeking an opportuinity to optimize that).

Is there some way I can do this macro more simple?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your first step should be to move the excel range into a VBA array.  Accessing a VBA array is much much faster that repeatedly accessing a single cell in an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things, and these are general guidelines.

**Firstly**, always declare your variables, especially in loops.  If you don't, the compiler needs to be determine what sort of variable it is and that adds overhead.

```
Dim x As Long, MaxX As Long, MaxY As Long, Target As Double
```

**Secondly**, turn off the screen updating and events, then, turn them back on again once you're done.  You'll also want to make sure you turn them back on if errors occur.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

**Thirdly**, if your logic doesn't rely on having the worksheet calculated when determining the next result, turn all calculations off.  In your example, store the values in VBA and work in memory rather than reading from the workbook each time, if you can avoid it.

**Finally**, as stated in the comments, use arrays where possible.

This sub routine will help you turn calculations, etc. on and off.

```
Public Sub ToggleCalcs(ByVal bOn As Boolean)
    Dim objSheet As Worksheet
 
    Application.EnableEvents = bOn
    Application.ScreenUpdating = bOn
    
    If bOn Then
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Else
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End If
    
    For Each objSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        objSheet.EnableCalculation = bOn
    Next
End Sub
```

The previous steps will help you you though and improve the performance.

Comment: I'd add `on error goto 0` to turn the events and screen updating back on

Comment: @FernandoJ.Rivera, yeah, I typically add a cleanup section at the bottom to ensure it always gets called.  I agree.