Excel vbscript populates defined table very slowly
The code below when populating a column of approx 300 cells executes quickly (10-15 seconds). However, the same code when populating cells in a defined table runs very slowly (10+ minutes). I assume it's something to do with the range being in a table so does anyone know why?

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'this pauses realtime cell populate

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
firstASXrow = 9 'row 9 is the start of my SD data dump

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'set ws to 'SData' sheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("SData")
ws.Activate

'ASX ticker column
Set tickercode = 12

'find the last ASX ticker in the ticker column
lastASXrow = 300

'MS Stock Code column
Set msStockCode = 10

'populate the MS Stock Code cells
For n = firstASXrow To lastASXrow
    ws.Range(Cells(n, msStockCode.Column), Cells(n, msStockCode.Column)).Value = "XASX:" & ws.Range(Cells(n, tickercode.Column), Cells(n, tickercode.Column)).Value
Continue:
    Next n

'bulk convert all the MS Stock Data cells Stocks DataType (ie. ServiceID268435456)
ws.Range(Cells(firstASXrow, msStockCode.Column), Cells(lastASXrow, msStockCode.Column)).ConvertToLinkedDataType ServiceID:=268435456, LanguageCulture:="en-US"

End Sub


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70058414/optimizing-a-vba-macro-to-work-on-multiple-rows-with-one-parameter/70059227#70059227

Start by determining how many new rows you're going to need and then use that value to resize your table prior to adding data to it.  Resizing ListObjects is fast and once you have the correct sized table, adding the data will run quickly.

The slowdown you're seeing when working with tables usually comes from the way Excel handles ListObjects. Tables have extra features (auto-expansion, structured references, and recalculating formulas), which can slow down code execution.
Turn off automatic recalculation: When you're updating a table, Excel might recalculate formulas constantly
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Use bulk updates instead of looping through each cell: Instead of updating cells one at a time in a loop, load the values into an array, modify the array, and then write the whole thing back to the sheet at once. This reduces the number of interactions with the table (which is the slow part).
For example:
Dim dataArray() As Variant
Dim i As Long

' Load data into an array
dataArray = ws.Range(Cells(firstASXrow, tickercode.Column), Cells(lastASXrow, tickercode.Column)).Value

' Update the array
For i = 1 To UBound(dataArray, 1)
    dataArray(i, 1) = "XASX:" & dataArray(i, 1)
Next i

' Write the array back to the worksheet
ws.Range(Cells(firstASXrow, msStockCode.Column), Cells(lastASXrow, msStockCode.Column)).Value = dataArray

Disable table auto-expansion if you don't need it.
 Application.AutoCorrect.AutoExpandListRange = False

Keep ScreenUpdating and DisplayAlerts off:
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


Copy Values Efficiently (in an Excel Table)

Adjust the table name and header titles.

Sub CreateStockCodes()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("SData")
    
    Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    Dim RowsCount As Long: RowsCount = lo.ListRows.Count
    If RowsCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no rows, just headers
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = lo.ListColumns("Ticker Code").DataBodyRange
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = lo.ListColumns("Stock Code").DataBodyRange
    
    Dim Data() As Variant, r As Long
    
    ' Read from source.
    If RowsCount = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = srg.Value
    Else
        Data = srg.Value
    End If
    ' Modify (usually has conditions).
    For r = 1 To RowsCount
        Data(r, 1) = "XASX:" & Data(r, 1)
    Next r
    ' Write to destination.
    drg.Value = Data
    
    drg.ConvertToLinkedDataType ServiceID:=268435456, LanguageCulture:="en-US"
    
    MsgBox "Stock codes created.", vbInformation
    
End Sub


All really good options here. I'm going with turning Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual as that's basically solved the problem for me but the other coding options look good as well so may use them in the future.
